# Why doesn't cc (the C compiler) and similar utilities use standard streams by default?

Tags: command-line, utilities, stdin, programming, standard

## Background

If think most of us agree that filters and pipes are the very foundation of Unix systems.

Pipes and filters are very powerful tools. Almost all Unix utilities use the standard input and output streams by default to make it possible to use them within pipelines.

It is a convention for utilities within Unix to operate *standard input* and *standard output* if no other input/output files have been specified.

`grep`, `as`, `sed`, `tr`, `perl`, `sort`, `uniq`, `bash`, `cmp`, `cat` and many others are all utilities that follow this convention.

But many programming utilities have abandoned this convention.

### Reading input

The most obvious example of this is `cc` (the C compiler).

If you invoke `cc` with no arguments you get this message:

```
ryvnf:~$ cc
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

This is not the only example of this:

```
ryvnf:~$ yacc
/usr/bin/bison: -y: missing operand
Try '/usr/bin/bison --help' for more information.
```

Lower-level utilities like `as` read *standard input* by default. I wonder why that is.

### Writing output

This also applies to output.

`cc` outputs its executable code into `a.out` by default. The parser generator `yacc` outputs its generated parser to `y.tab.c`.

To me using standard input/output streams by default is advantageous because then you can easily connect various utilities. Like this pipe which compiles a yacc parser to executable code in one go without generating intermediate files like `y.tab.c`:

```
yacc parser.y | cc -o parser
```

## My question

Why is it that utilities for programming don't use the standard streams by default as many other Unix utilities do?

What is the motivation for not using *standard input streams* by default for these utilities?

**Note** that I am aware that you can get `cc` to read *standard input* by using `cc -x c -`. This works but my question remains why it doesn't do this by default.

Comment: I would guess that it's because these things are meant to act on source files, which you usually don't generate programmatically; they don't fit that well into the standard Unix 'filter' metaphor, because both their inputs and their outputs are meant to be objects in and of themselves.

Comment: Why should it do that by default? Why shouldn't it read from file by default? What if you have multiple files? Why read file, and not filepaths? How would this be of any use for programs larger than one file?

Comment: @MatthewRock There are many languages that generate C code as an intermediate language. It would be easier to filter their output through `cc` if standard input/output was used by default.

Comment: Most compilers write their output to object files etc. because that's what most people prefer as a default. They don't want to further process it.

Comment: What are these languages? Is this one file? How would this be easier? Were these languages around when cc was designed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipelines don't work for source code because you can't process input as it comes in.  You need the entire file loaded before processing begins.  It gets even worse when you need multiple files for compilation (.h files for example).  If you were reading from stdin you would need to stream in all of the needed files with some method of specifying file breaks between the files you piped in.  The problems just grow from there.

The idea behind the pipeline was that it would be a series of simple tasks.  Compiling code is *NOT* a simple task and so it was never designed to be a part of a pipeline.  Also pipeline theory said that all communication between processes in the pipeline should be in plain text to facilitate portability of individual components.  By definition the output of `cc` or `yacc` or `ld` or anything else involved in compiling code is binary data which doesn't fit the model.